# Refactoring the use of SqlConnection more than once in 1 class

Tags: c#

I have some code which forms a database-centric class  which performs CRUD operation. Insert() and Select() methods use the same connection string. At the moment, both methods are repetitive by repeating the standard bit of setting up a SqlConnection.

How best should this be refactored? Should I have a property for SqlConnection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pull all your DB operations out into a single class, and pass the class to the objects that need it. You can do this via constructor injection (each new object gets an IDBProvider passed to it which it then uses for database operations).

Something like this:

```
public interface IDBProvider {
   // ... list of DB operations you care about
   List<Products> GetProducts(string vendor)
}

public class SomeWorkerClass {
   private IDBProvider dbConnection;

   public SomeWorkerClass(IDBProvider dbProvider) {
      dbConnection = dbProvider;
   }

   public void SomeFunction() {
      List<Products> = dbConnection.GetProducts("test");
   } 
}
```

There are lots of frameworks that do this kind of stuff for you, like [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html), but in some cases its just as easy to roll your own (upgrading existing code, organizations that dont want external framework dependencies, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it one of two ways.

- A class that contains static methods and properties to connect to a database. I can then use it in any other class I need.
- A SqlConnection property in a class that connects to databases. I then inject the connection from the controlling class when I need it.

By far the first option is used most frequently. The only issue is that if the database server changes, I need to recompile the class. We only have one database server, though, and it doesn't change that often, so it really isn't that much of an issue.

The good thing about the second option is that it's a lot more flexible; if the server, user, or password changes it's as simple as updating that information in the controlling class.

Comment: With the 2nd approach, do you mean the connection comes from the class which makes a call to a member of the class which connects to the db/has the sqlconnection?

Comment: Yes, or, at the very least, a ConnectionString is passed into the class that does the database work. The idea is that you have a "master" class that runs the show (which is where your SqlConnection or ConnectionString would get created and be maintained) and each of the "slave" classes that actually do the database work would receive that connection upon their creation. That way you only have to maintain the SqlConnection in one place.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your application. As far as I'm concerned: No. You might want to add a new method to set up the connection (that might even be a good idea), but a connection as field/property sounds like "I open a connection for the whole lifetime of my form", which is evil in my world.

Create a helper method and write something like

```
using (var connection = CreateSqlConnection()) {
  // Do the operations here
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to have the connection open all the time; it's adequate merely to pass the connection (or a ConnectionString) for use when needed.

Comment: Michael, that's what I said. At least that's what I meant and I cannot see where the text is ambiguos?

Comment: I was under the impression you assumed that the connection didn't just exist but that it also maintained an open state throughout its lifetime. If that's not correct, I misunderstood you.